# SharePoint 2010 - Use workflow to add multiple entries in a look-up field

Tags: workflow, lookup-column

So setting the environment first.

List A - Item Request
Field 1 - Request Item Name (Single Line Text)
Field 2 - Current Requirements (Lookup field from List B with multiple selections allowed)

List B - Requirements
Field 1 - Requirement (Single Line Text)
Field 2 - Requested Item Name (Lookup field from List A)

So the workflow I have works like this.  When someone enters an item into list B, the workflow will go to List A find the matching Request Item Name and add the Requirement to the Current Requirements field.  That's okay works fine.

However if another item is added with the same Request Item Name it'll overwrite what is in the Current Requirements field, even though it's set to allow for multiple selections.  How do I keep the workflow from overwriting?  I need it to add it to the field so that all requirements are listed for each item.

On a side note if used a multi-line text box with "append" it did list all the requirements but removed the hyperlink.  I would like to keep the hyperlink function.

So I either need:
a) The lookup field to add more entries when the workflow is triggered

or

b) A multi-line text field that keeps the hyperlink
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could create a new variable string that should be something like:

```
Set workflowvariable to "[Current Item: Lookup Field];[New Lookup Value Id]"
Set LookupField to workflowvariable
```

Comment: Unfortunately it's not working.  If you were able to get it to work can you paste the entire workflow (all fields that you filled in).  Maybe I'm missing something.